# Generar una consulta con relación a dos tablas diferentes desde un mismo campo

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, subconsultas

Dentro una consulta mayor tengo la siguiente condición, desde la cual obtengo información de dos tablas distintas:

```
(CASE WHEN VentaLista.TipoArticuloid = '3' THEN
(SELECT Servicio.Nombre, '' AS Marca, '' AS Modelo, '' AS linea
FROM Servicio 
WHERE Servicio.Id = VentaLista.ArticuloId) ELSE
(SELECT Producto.Nombre, Proveedor.Nombre AS Marca, Producto.Modelo, 
Producto.Linea
FROM Producto 
INNER JOIN SucursalInventario
ON Producto.Id = SucursalInventario.ProductoId
INNER JOIN Proveedor
ON Producto.ProveedorId = Proveedor.Id
WHERE SucursalInventario.Id = VentaLista.ArticuloId) END) AS Articulo,
```

Recientemente he tenido que modificarla para que en el caso de los productos muestre la información de su marca, modelo y linea, sin embargo estoy obteniendo el siguiente error

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

En efecto en las subconsultas solo es posible obtener un solo valor

Estaba pensando en la posibilidad de generar una consulta en la que se incluya la relación a través de JOIN o UNION, pero no tengo idea de como
establecer la condición a partir del campo TipoArticuloId

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que tu sub-query te está retornando más de un valor; lo que debes hacer es poner un Top 1 o utilizar Exists que es lo que te indica el error.

*Top 1*
    Select *
    From TablaA a 
    where a.ID in (Select top 1 b.ID from TablaB)

**Exists**
    Select *
    From TablaA a
    where Exists ( Select 1 from TablaB b where a.ID = b.ID)

Se selecciona un 1 porque lo que se necesita es validar si la fila existe o no.

Comment: hice la modificacion, pero aun estoy obteniendo el error, quiza no entendi como es que debo aplicar la consulta:

Comment: No cabe la consulta modificada en la caja de comentarios :V

Comment: (SELECT Servicio.Codigo, Servicio.Nombre, '' AS Marca
FROM Servicio
WHERE Servicio.Id IN (SELECT TOP(1) Servicio.Id FROM Servicio WHERE Servicio.Id = VentaLista.ArticuloId)) 
ELSE
(SELECT Producto.Codigo, Producto.Nombre, Proveedor.Nombre AS Marca
FROM Producto 
INNER JOIN SucursalInventario
ON Producto.Id = SucursalInventario.ProductoId
INNER JOIN Proveedor
ON Producto.ProveedorId = Proveedor.Id
WHERE SucursalInventario.Id IN (SELECT TOP(1) SucursalInventario.Id FROM SucursalInventario WHERE
 SucursalInventario.Id = VentaLista.ArticuloId)) END) AS Articulo,